# How to update/upgrade Python (2.6 to 3.5) version using Pip?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to upgrade python version 2.6 to 3.5 using pip on a virtual environment but don't know correct command.

Comment: _but getting errors_ .can you please add it to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upgade python version using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769109/upgade-python-version-using-pip)

Comment: Also, please show the commands you are running.

Comment: @scharette I am trying to find out correct command

Comment: You can't upgrade Python itself with pip

Comment: Assuming you have Python 3.5 installed already, the usual procedure for upgrading a virtualenv is to create a _new_ virtualenv with the new Python version and then reinstall your packages into the new virtualenv. Trying to upgrade a virtualenv in place is unlikely to work well.

Comment: @Blurp I need to each time start virtual env and install from scratch, each time its taking python 2.6 and not any newer version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the python version that a virtual environment uses in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302931/how-to-change-the-python-version-that-a-virtual-environment-uses-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

Just install the python3 and use an alias.  Removing python2 from your system is a very bad idea.

Answer (score -2):

Install Python3.x

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.x
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.x
```

Then change the default Python

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

Check the default

```
 python -V
```

Comment: Removing/replacing the system Python is a bad idea.

Comment: @Jack_hpb What OS are you using?

Comment: @Blurp Mac Os X

Comment: Could you add your errors while installing? Which installation package do you use in your virtual machine?(apt,yum,pacman etc.)